# Derivative of the integral of a function that needs to be integrated by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone explain to me why $$\frac{d}{da}\left(\int_{-\infty}^a(a-x)f(x)dx)\right) = (a-x)f(x)|_a+\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx$$

I saw it in a solution to a problem I was working on and don't understand.

Comment: The property its called "leibniz integral rule". Hope help you.

Comment: It looks like integration by parts but it's not. It's really an application of chain rule where $$g(s,t) = \int_{-\infty}^sf(t,x)dx$$ but then you also have $s(a) = t(a) = a$ $$\frac{dg}{da} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{da} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{da}$$

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of solution:

$\phi(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a(a-x)f(x)dx = a\int^a_{-\infty}f(x)\,dx - \int^a_{-\infty} xf(x)\,dx$

Then, using the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus

$\phi'(a)=\int^a_{-\infty} f(x)\,dx + af(a) - a f(a)=\int^a_{-\infty} f(x)\,dx$